# Не выполняется ajax в Laravel 5.4

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel5

js

```
(function($, undefined){
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $('#lg-search').on('click', function () {
        var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

        $.ajax({ //На этой строке ошибка filter.js: 27
            method: 'post',
            url: 'treatment',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { "_method": "POST", "_token": token, message: "Answer from ajax" },
            success: function (response) {
                console.log("Response: " + response)
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log("Error: " + data)
            }
        });
    });
```

роут

```
Route::post('/treatment', 'FilterController@treatment')->name('treatment');
```

контроллер

```
/**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function treatment(Request $request)
    {
        if(Request::ajax()){

            return response()->json($request['message'], 201);
        }
    }
```

вываливает ошибку:

```
jquery.min.js:4 POST https://домен.ru/treatment 500 ()
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ filter.js:27 //В этой строчке - $.ajax({ и все
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?
P.S. Использую Laravel 5.4

Answer (score 0):

Решено!

1. Добавить в контроллер строку

   use Illuminate\Http\Request;
2. И в методе treatment вместо Request::ajax() -> $request->ajax().